HMAC-SHA256 hash using OpenSSL does not match hash from online tools
I am trying to use OpenSSL 3.4.0 to generate an HMAC hash EVP_sha256. However, I am not able to match my generated hash to online tools (tried: base32 encoded key for each side).
Here is my source code:
libtotp.hpp
#ifndef TOTP_LIB_LIBTOTP_HPP
#define TOTP_LIB_LIBTOTP_HPP

#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>


int gen_secret(unsigned char *buffer, int buffer_size);
int hmac_sha256(const unsigned char *key, int key_size, const unsigned char *data, int data_size, unsigned char *md_buffer, unsigned int md_size);

#endif //TOTP_LIB_LIBTOTP_HPP

libtotp.cpp:
#include "libtotp.hpp"

int gen_secret(unsigned char *buffer, int buffer_size) {
  int status = RAND_bytes(buffer, buffer_size);
  if (status != 1) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int hmac_sha256(const unsigned char *key, int key_size, const unsigned char *data, int data_size, unsigned char *md_buffer, unsigned int md_size) {
  if (md_size < 32) return -2;
  if (!HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, key_size, data, data_size, md_buffer, &md_size)) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

main.cpp:
#include "libtotp.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
  unsigned char secret[20];
  gen_secret(secret, sizeof(secret) / sizeof(unsigned char));

  // raw secret
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    std::cout << secret[i];
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  // hex secret
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int)secret[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  std::string data = "some data to be hashed";
  const unsigned char* data_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data.c_str());
  unsigned char md_buffer[32];
  hmac_sha256(secret, sizeof(secret), data_ptr, data.size(), md_buffer, sizeof(md_buffer));

  // hex hmac-sha256 hashed result
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int)md_buffer[i] << " ";
  }
}

My program printed the following output:
I؆�����g$R~ib��`
49 d8 86 99 9b 10 fa b3 b7 67 24 52 7e 12 69 62 83 13 88 60 
4f 2f bc b8 3e 92 77 78 77 0e ab 4f 57 b3 09 f1 88 33 53 e7 a6 7f 16 20 6d c5 f5 a5 6a 26 95 b4

Yet, online tools gave something else for the same key and data. I have tried encoding the key (program) with base32 and base64, encoding the key (online tools) with base32 and base64, and using fixed string to run hmac_sha256().

Openssl won't be expecting the key to be encoded, just put in the raw key bytes

The output of your code seems to be OK, CyberChef returns the same result: https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=HMAC(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'49d886999b10fab3b76724527e12696283138860'%7D,'SHA256')&input=c29tZSBkYXRhIHRvIGJlIGhhc2hlZA The problem is probably due to your online tool or incorrect handling.
